# Saving a high number of images as an array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a high number of videos and I want to extract the frames, pre-process them and then create an array for each video . So far I have created the arrays but the final size of each array is too big for all of the videos. I have 224 videos, each resulting in a 6GB array totaling more than 1.2TB. I have tried using numpy.save and pickle.dump but both create the same size on the system. Do you have a recommendation or an alternative way in general?

Comment: `save` is the pickle format for numpy arrays, so yes the size should be the same.  File size should be similar to the array size, a byte dump of the array's data buffer.

Comment: Video has highly redundant data, which is why video files can be su much smaller than the uncompressed data. Store the videos as video files, you can read them from there when you need to use the data. Why would you want to store the uncompressed data?

Comment: I guess you are searching for a compression library. eg. Blosc is a really fast library. http://python-blosc.blosc.org/tutorial.html But compression ratio highly depends on the data. At first just try to zip a npy- file and than post the results.

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these steps for each of the videos:

1. Load the data into one NumPy array.
2. Write to disk using `np.save()` with the extension `.npy`.
3. Add the `.npy` file to a `.zip` compressed archive using the `zipfile` module.

The end result will be as if you loaded all 224 arrays and saved them at once using `np.savez_compressed`, but it will only use enough RAM to process a single video at a time, instead of having to store all the uncompressed data in memory at once.

Finally, `np.load()` (or `zipfile`) can be used to load the data from disk, one video at a time, or even using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` to load multiple files at once using multiple cores for decompression to save time (you can get speedup almost linear with the number of cores, if your disk is fast).